# Melting and boiling point trend in Group II

Tags: elements, boiling-point, melting-point

The following picture shows the melting and boiling point trends down group II elements.

[image: Melting and boiling points of group II elements, done with Excel 2016]

I have added question marks where the variability in data was rather disturbing (over two hundred degrees Celsius), or where the value is simply disputed. Nevertheless, this topic is not about the different results from measurements. Instead, it focuses on the "trend" in general.

For group I, we would say

- the number of electron shells increases,
- the increasing number of protons is unable to compensate for this fact,
- therefore, atomic radius increases and
- electronegativity, ionisation energies decrease,
- hence the metallic bond is weaker $\Rightarrow$ melting and boiling points decrease
- atomisation energy decreases.

Here are the atomic radii and ionisation energies of group II elements.

[image: The atomic radii and ionisation energies of group II elements, done with Excel 2016]

These (apart from radium) do seem to follow the same logic as in group I, however they do not correlate with the melting or boiling points. Some textbooks claim,

> A good measure for the strength of a metallic bond is its atomisation energy.

Let us have a look.

[image: Atomisation energies of group II elements, done with Excel 2016]

Sure, this does agree better with the boiling and melting points. But note that it is actually not an explanation! Why do the atomisation energies behave in such a way?

This is where most resources either

1. ignore the problem altogether by not mentioning it,
2. give an explanation which is claimed by others to be faulty,
3. few acknowledge the issue and say no *simple* explanation is possible.

**The *faulty* explanation**

Beryllium and magnesium have crystal lattices that are hexagonal closest-packed (close-packed?). Therefore, they have their own trend. Then there are calcium and strontium which have face-centered cubic lattices. Finally, the pair barium and radium have body-centered cubic structures.

Others say this is not enough, because the differences should not be as significant, especially for magnesium but also for barium. Barium has a 8-coordinated structure but has a higher boiling point than 12-coordinated strontium!

It might also be stated that melting points themselves are not the best estimator of the strength of bonds. The bonds are not all broken, but rather rearranged and "made weaker" as a result.

**The question**

As of now, is there an explanation for melting and boiling point trends of group II elements? Is there consensus?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32635/why-does-magnesium-have-an-exceptionally-low-melting-point

Comment: This paper seems to have a quantitative explanation https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.62.14818 but I don't really understand the paper from a brief skimming.

Comment: My 50 point bounty expired with no acceptable answer. Too bad, but it was worth the try.

Comment: @EdV I am inactive on Chem, but the bounty was appreciated, thank you. Indeed worth the try.

Comment: There can be no rigorous answer to such questions I think. We have no more than six data points, and each of them is just the way it is. The reason for the melting points is of course the crystal structure, and the bond properties therein. It can be nothing else, but of course that doesn´t explain much.

Comment: A clarifying note on the 'faulty' explanation - Be changes from hcp to bcc at 1527K, before melting at 1560K. Mg is the only one that goes from hcp->liquid.

Answer (score 1):

Its goes down because the attraction between electrons in sea of electrons and cations in the metal lattice becomes weaker therefore less energy is required to interrupt the lattice and easier to melt .

Comment: What are you saying dude? Please read the question first